# How do I run a function on a loop just once?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In `on_ready` I run eternal function in loop like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.loop.create_task(some_function())
```

But then this functions runs multiple times (probably because of auto restarts by pm2). How can I make sure that this function were ran just once?

Comment: Not knowing anything about discord, it sounds like `on_ready` isn't the right place for creating this task.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a boolean flag to record that you've called `create_task`. Only call it if you've never called it before:

```
done = False

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    if not done:
        bot.loop.create_task(some_function())
        done = True
```

Comment: solid approach.

Comment: Yes, I know about flags. I just want to ask about discord.py feature for that. I saw one decorator there but not sure. And I forgot its name.